# Rails: .create nullifies a custom value for :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel, seed

When I execute a Model.create method, if I specify a value for :id, it later gets nullified. Example:

```
Model.create (
  :id => 50,
  :name => Joe,
  :enabled => yes
)
```

Instead what I have to do is use a .new and store it in a class variable, store my id value via the class variable, and then finally call a save:

```
m = Model.new (
  :name => Joe,
  :enabled => yes
)

m.id = 50
m.save
```

I am trying to execute this code in a seeds.rb, and this is NOT very DRY code. How can I do this better and achieve the same results?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? It's outside of Rails convention, so sure it won't be DRY (Rails "punishes" you for getting outside of convention).

Comment: It's not even a matter of Rails conventions, it's a matter of relational database conventions. If you are relying on primary keys having certain values in your logic (`do_something if user.id == 50`) you need to rethink what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id is just attr_protected. To prevent that, you can override the list of default protected attributes. Be careful doing this anywhere that attribute information can come from the outside. The id field is default protected for a reason.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   private
   def attributes_protected_by_default
      []
   end
end
```

or go with @Leo answer

Comment: YES! Thanks, you taught me something new today and this makes a lot of sense! Agreed, this is something every RoR developer should be extra cautious on utilizing.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an answer for you. Model.create is basically a Model.new followed by a Model.save and since you are changing the id and saving again you might as well do

```
m = Model.new { 
  :name => Joe,
  :enabled => yes
}
m.id = 50
m.save!
```

That will rid you of doing two saves.

Comment: My bad. I was using a `Model.new`, but I was too quick on the copy/paste for my question. Sorry. I Edited my original question to correct this.